# How can Add username and password as URL parameter in Android SOAP webservices program with SAP SOAP WSDL?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I added the Username and password as URL parameter the fallowing URL:

`private static final String URL ="http://*********:****/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_14DAE9C8D79F1EE193CF0AB8FEE64345/wsdl11/allino‌​ne/ws_policy/document?sap-client=*****&UserName=*******&password=******";`

I got the following Exception:

> :02-24 12:37:44.159: WARN/System.err(530): java.net.SocketTimeoutException 02-24 12:37:44.159: WARN/System.err(530): at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:130

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try the same URL in the desktop browser and check that the server is accessible and the URL is correct.

try The following code:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(...);
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.encodeBytes("login:password".getBytes()));
```

Assuming you are using HttpClient. Following is a example of [HttpClient](http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/)

Comment: I RUN in the desktop Browser It asking Username and password .when ever i entered Credentials it Shows the WSDL file .How can i give Username and password through program In android .

Thanks for ur reply

Comment: Thanks For Ur reply I am using the fallowing code for Soap Webservices in Androidpackage com.appule.pack;


import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;